# Lambda variable vs function reference

Tags: kotlin

What is the difference between storing a lambda in a variable and reuse that, vs using a function reference?

for example a simple filter:

```
val strings = listOf("One", null, "Three")

val noNulls: (String?) -> Boolean = { value -> value != null }
strings.filter(noNulls)
```

vs

```
fun noNulls(value: String?): Boolean = value != null
strings.filter(::noNulls)
```

Comment: In terms of behaviour, the end result is the same for both. What kind of differences are you looking for? Performance differences? Bytecode differences?

Comment: @byxor a general best practice consensus among the community maybe. Possible pitfalls. I know theres a minor difference in the bytecode, the lambda version generates some extra variables i believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both cases this will be compiled for the JVM as a dedicated class that implements the behavior of the object you pass to `filter`.

You should use nested function declarations if your intent is to call them within the declared scope; if your intent is to get a function object, then use the feature meant specifically for that: the lambda expression.